# How to specify dynamic url in django template for class based view using router?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

```
path('index/api-root/', include((router.urls, 'api'), namespace='api-root')),
path('index/' , home, name='home'),
path('about/' , about, name='about'),
```

my router

```
router.register('bankdetailapi', views.BankViewSet, basename='bankdetail' )
```

how i wrote urls in template

```
href="{% url 'about' %}"
href="{% url 'api-root' %}"
href="{% url 'home' %}"
```

i am getting following error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\JAY SARDAR\projects\Django+Angular\Fyle-assignment\Backend\restapi\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 47, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "C:\Users\JAY SARDAR\projects\Django+Angular\Fyle-assignment\Backend\restapi\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 181, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\JAY SARDAR\projects\Django+Angular\Fyle-assignment\Backend\restapi\rest_api\api\views.py", line 36, in home
    return render(request,'index.html')
  File "C:\Users\JAY SARDAR\projects\Django+Angular\Fyle-assignment\Backend\restapi\lib\site-packages\django\shortcuts.py", line 19, in render
    content = loader.render_to_string(template_name, context, request, using=using)
  File "C:\Users\JAY SARDAR\projects\Django+Angular\Fyle-assignment\Backend\restapi\lib\site-packages\django\template\loader.py", line 62, in render_to_string
    return template.render(context, request)
  File "C:\Users\JAY SARDAR\projects\Django+Angular\Fyle-assignment\Backend\restapi\lib\site-packages\django\template\backends\django.py", line 61, in render
    return self.template.render(context)
  File "C:\Users\JAY SARDAR\projects\Django+Angular\Fyle-assignment\Backend\restapi\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 170, in render
    return self._render(context)
  File "C:\Users\JAY SARDAR\projects\Django+Angular\Fyle-assignment\Backend\restapi\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 162, in _render
    return self.nodelist.render(context)
  File "C:\Users\JAY SARDAR\projects\Django+Angular\Fyle-assignment\Backend\restapi\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 938, in render
    bit = node.render_annotated(context)
  File "C:\Users\JAY SARDAR\projects\Django+Angular\Fyle-assignment\Backend\restapi\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 905, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
  File "C:\Users\JAY SARDAR\projects\Django+Angular\Fyle-assignment\Backend\restapi\lib\site-packages\django\template\loader_tags.py", line 150, in render
    return compiled_parent._render(context)
  File "C:\Users\JAY SARDAR\projects\Django+Angular\Fyle-assignment\Backend\restapi\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 162, in _render
    return self.nodelist.render(context)
  File "C:\Users\JAY SARDAR\projects\Django+Angular\Fyle-assignment\Backend\restapi\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 938, in render
    bit = node.render_annotated(context)
  File "C:\Users\JAY SARDAR\projects\Django+Angular\Fyle-assignment\Backend\restapi\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 905, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
  File "C:\Users\JAY SARDAR\projects\Django+Angular\Fyle-assignment\Backend\restapi\lib\site-packages\django\template\defaulttags.py", line 446, in render
    url = reverse(view_name, args=args, kwargs=kwargs, current_app=current_app)
  File "C:\Users\JAY SARDAR\projects\Django+Angular\Fyle-assignment\Backend\restapi\lib\site-packages\django\urls\base.py", line 86, in reverse
    return resolver._reverse_with_prefix(view, prefix, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\JAY SARDAR\projects\Django+Angular\Fyle-assignment\Backend\restapi\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py", line 694, in _reverse_with_prefix
    raise NoReverseMatch(msg)

Exception Type: NoReverseMatch at /index/
Exception Value: Reverse for 'api-root' not found. 'api-root' is not a valid view function or pattern name.
```

When i change url for api as hard coded http link everything works fine. I think syntax for writing router urls is different. Also how to write href for Basename parameter?

Comment: https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/routers/#simplerouter - look at URL Name column. Viewset actions are determinated based on basename eg. in your example `bankdetail-list` - `list` action in the viewset, `bankdetail-detail` - `retrieve` action etc.

Comment: what i am asking is something different. i want to specify url for `http://127.0.0.1:8000/api-root/bankdetailapi/` where bankdetail is basename . i dont want any actions. lets say i want to redirect on api page just in case .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
"{% url 'api:api-root' %}bankdetailapi/?q=">
```

Solved my problem. How did it work? After several trial and error, I found this to be working:

```
"{% url 'app_name:namespace'%}basename/query_parameter"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
href="{% url 'api:api-root' %}"
```

apparently it was very easy.
you have to use `"{% url 'app_name:namespace' %}"` for it to work when you are including router. But still I cant find how to use url for basename parameters.